# Access Outside Variable inside a internal function typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have one variable outside a function that I need to change the value. I normally use "this" to access the variable but at that point of the code, "this" is not reachable.

```
export class GamesDetailPage {

  details : any = {};
  type : String;
  level : Number; 
  cards : any = {}; // THE VARIABLE I WANT TO SET THE VALUE


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HttpClient , private device: Device, private serviceProvider: ServicesProvider,     
                                            public navParams: NavParams
) {
    this.type = navParams.get('gameType');
    this.level = navParams.get('gameLevel');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {


    this.getCards();  // WHERE I CALL THE METHOD  
  }


  getCards(){
    var deviceUUID = this.device.uuid;
    var platform =  this.device.platform;
    var cardsReq = {"gameType": this.type ,"gameLevel": this.level};
    var dialog = this.dialogs;

   this.serviceProvider.getCards(deviceUUID, platform, cardsReq)

    .then(function (res){
      this.cards = res;// HERE I WANT TO SET THE VARIABLE BUT "THIS" IS UNDEFINED
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log("Error");
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you need to use [`ES6 arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as in the earlier `(function(){` method `this` does not refer to the class but in the es6 one it will...

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this

```
.then( 
(res) => {
      this.cards = res; // Should work now
    }
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the outter `this` is shadowed by `this` of the function.
The most straight forward way and also the recommend way is to use arrow function in typescript.

Change the lambda function to:

```
(res) => {}
```

Another old solution is save `this` to a temp variable:

```
that = this
```

and then access that inside your lambda function.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript `this` relates to the current function. TypeScript just hides this fact when it transpiles your code.

As a result, there are two things you can do.

First you could use ES6 arrow functions (TypeScript will do the `this` scoping for you)

```
.then((res) => {
    this.cards = res;
})
```

Alternatively you could handle it yourself

```
getCards(){
    var _this = this;

    // More code

    .then(function (res){
        _this.cards = res;
    })
```

If you check the transpiled output for both cases they should be almost the same